# Coq: proof of "lens is closed under composition"

Tags: functional-programming, coq, proof, lenses

I'm a functional programmer completely new to Coq. In fact, I've just finished [Mike Naha's tutorial](https://coq.inria.fr/tutorial-nahas). Particularly, I'm interested in this language to formalize some laws related to optics. For example, I'd like to know how to encode that [lens is closed under composition](https://gist.github.com/jeslg/c4e141770ac9f47a2def3712192e125b).

I started to deal with *GetPut*. The aforementioned tutorial doesn't cover records, but I think they're what I need to encode a lens. As far as I know, the composition method should be implemented as a *Definition*. Finally, I assume that my theorem needs to receive evidences of *GetPut* for the composing lenses, to prove that the same law holds for the resulting lens by means of an equality. Not very helpful, but this is my (incomplete and wrong) proof skeleton:

```
Record lens (S : Type) (A : Type) := mkLens {
  get : S -> A;
  put : S -> A -> S }.

Definition compose_ln (S A B : Type) (ln1: lens S A) (ln2 : lens A B) : lens S B :=
  {| get := fun (s : S) => get ln1 s;
     put := fun (s : S) (a : A) => put ln1 s (put ln2 (get ln1 s) a) |}.

Theorem closed_GetPut :
    (forall S A B : Type,
    (forall (s : S),
    (forall (ln1 : lens S A) (ln2 : lens A B),
    (exists GetPut_proof : ln1 (* ln1 holds GetPut? *)),
    (exists GetPut_proof : ln2 (* ln2 holds GetPut? *)),
    (put (compose_ln ln1 ln2) s (get (compose_ln ln1 ln2) s) = s)))).
Proof.
  (* ... *)
Qed.
```

Having said so:

- Am I in the right path to write this proof? Is there any other way to better approach it?
- Where can I find similar examples to be used as guiding examples?
- Based on my FP background, what's the better material to keep on learning Coq? (I was thinking on [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/) by Benjamin C. Pierce.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks roughly reasonable, but it needs some tidying.

First, you might as well remove the two "exists" quantifiers (change them into plain implications).

Second, the types of the two last assumptions should not be just "ln1" and "ln2" but something like "very_well_behaved ln1" and "very_well_behaved ln2".  (And then the type of the final result can be "very_well_behaved (compose ln2 ln2)".

Comment: Sure, that's a nicer structure! However, I can't see what's behind `very_well_behaved` right now. My `exists` intuition was based on the section *"hd with a proof that the list is non-empty"* from [Naha's tutorial](https://coq.inria.fr/tutorial-nahas). Is `very_well_behaved` similar to `hd_never_fail` (replacing `safety_proof` by `GetPut`, `PutGet`, etc.)? I mean, is it a definition?

Comment: What you want is to define a property (i.e., a function from lenses to Prop) that says what it means for a lens to be very well behaved.  Then the theorem becomes "if the two lenses are very well behaved, then their composition is too."

Comment: Taking a look at the first volume of Software Foundations is probably a pretty efficient way to get up to speed on all this.

Comment: Great, I'll take that way. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

After reading the first chapters of [Logical Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/index.html) (which I definitely recommend if your background is *functional*) I'm able to implement the proof that lens is closed under composition in Coq. Firstly, we need to define `lens` and `compose`:

```
Record lens (S A : Type) := {
  get : S -> A;
  put : S -> A -> S }.

Definition compose {S A B : Type} (ln1 : lens S A) (ln2 : lens A B) : lens S B :=
  {| get := fun (s : S) => ln2.(get A B) (ln1.(get S A) s);
     put := fun (s : S) (b : B) => ln1.(put S A) s (ln2.(put A B) (ln1.(get S A) s) b) |}.
```

*(*) Notice the fixed syntax to access the fields of the record.*

Then, we need to declare the involved properties, to finally reach `very_well_behaved` (suggested by @Benjamin Pierce in the accepted answer):

```
Definition get_put {S A : Type} (ln : lens S A) : Prop :=
  forall (s : S), ln.(put S A) s (ln.(get S A) s) = s.

Definition put_get {S A : Type} (ln : lens S A) : Prop :=
  forall (s : S) (a : A), ln.(get S A) (ln.(put S A) s a) = a.

Definition put_put {S A : Type} (ln : lens S A) : Prop :=
  forall (s : S) (a1 : A) (a2 : A), 
    ln.(put S A) (ln.(put S A) s a1) a2 = ln.(put S A) s a2.

Definition very_well_behaved {S A : Type} (ln : lens S A) : Prop :=
  get_put ln /\ put_get ln /\ put_put ln.
```

Once the properties are defined, the next (and biggest) challenge consists on proving that very well-behaved lenses are closed under composition. To do so, we can use the following theorem skeleton:

```
Theorem compose_is_closed : forall (S A B : Type) (ln1 : lens S A) (ln2 : lens A B),
    very_well_behaved ln1 -> very_well_behaved ln2 -> very_well_behaved (compose ln1 ln2).
Proof.
  (* tactics here *)
Qed.
```

Right now, my Coq knowledge is quite limited, that's why I don't include the tactics here, since I feel that my current implementation is still naive. Anyway, if you're curious about it, you can find the whole proof [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/jeslg/f21c93a8ca6b8587949cc084692e9587).

Comment: I've published a blog post ([Lens, State is your father... and I can prove it!](https://blog.hablapps.com/2018/01/24/lens-state-is-your-father-and-i-can-prove-it/)) where we show proofs very similar to this one, just in case you are interested.